# Angular - Node - Possible to tell node which block from routes request from

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Is it possible to tell a request to my Node App `req` in:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/site/index.html')
});
```

From which block of my Angular routes it is from (i.e. I want to be able to identify whats from the `otherwise` block);

```
.when('/user',
    {...}
  )
.when('/login',
    {...}
  )
  .otherwise(
    {...}
  )
```

The reason I want it because I want to do something like:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  if (req is from otherwise block) {
     res.status(400).sendFile(__dirname + '/site/index.html')
  } else {
     res.sendFile(__dirname + '/site/index.html')
  }
});
```

The only thing i can otherwise think of is to create an array of all the allowed routes but I don't like duplication :p

Comment: You can just grab `req.originalUrl`

Comment: @brandonscript - thanks but thats not what I need - I've updated my question with why i want it

Comment: Since the only link between Angular and Node is the HTTP request it's making, all you can do is retrieve the url and analyze which route it came from. Alternatively, you could just set up your Node routes to match, and then you'd know?

Comment: @brandonscript - thanks. Just wondering then how people handle 404s - i.e. not just showing a page saying 404 but actually having the status code in the header? Looks like I'm going to have to make an array with routes from Angular :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the only link between Angular and Node is the HTTP request it's making, all you can do is retrieve the url and analyze which route it came from.

I'd define the routes you know about in Node, and then have a fallback for 404 errors:

```
app.get(['/login', '/user'], function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/site/index.html')
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.status(404).sendFile(__dirname + '/site/404.html')
});
```

Comment: Thanks - thats the route I ended up on - after a days investigation :p